# How many Droids could the CIS Trade Federation landing craft carry?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars, trade-federation

I have seen sources that say things like how many droids does the landing craft carry, but does that include the droids in the Multi Troop Carriers? Because there are 11 Multi Troop Carriers and a lot of Platoon Attack craft, so with the number of droids inside of the Landing craft combined with how many droids are in the crafts that are *also* in the landing craft, how many droids *really are* in the landing craft in total?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  It would help if you showed your work; what figures do you already have, and what inconsistencies do you need to resolve to get a final number?

Comment: Thank you for the welcome. I appreciate it. :)

Comment: Oh! Whoops! It said Traid?! Thank you so much for catching that. o_o;

Comment: I'm guessing that the answer is somewhere between "several" and "a lot"

Comment: @Wasabi No problem, it's all part of doing a review.  In terms of your actual question, I couldn't find anything that suggested there were droids, except crew, that _weren't_ in carriers.

Comment: Figures... well I know that there are 11 Multi Troop Carriers, 571 droideka, 38 platoon attack craft, 164 OOM security battle droids, 39 OOM pilot battle droids, 30 OOM repair droids, 40 OOM command battle droids, and 4368 B-1 battle droids in the landing craft excluding the droids in other crafts such as the MTC and the PAC inside of the Landing craft.

Comment: The landing craft of the CIS is huge. It also never had any living crew, only on some rare occasions.

Comment: but the OOM's and the battle droids listed above, those are only of the Landing Craft itself. So I'm wondering how much droids are total, MTC carry a lot of droids themselves.

Comment: "4368 B-1 battle droids in the landing craft excluding the droids in other crafts such as the MTC and the PAC inside of the Landing craft." I think that's wrong; that is exactly the complement (112 * (11 + 28) = 4368) _carried_ by the MTTs and PACs.  I don't think they had any non-crew droids on there that weren't in carriers.

Comment: So you're saying that the source may be wrong? It seems you're right, because MTC's *do* in fact have 112 droids, so does that mean that it has 4368 droids total? What about droideka? (Also, what is the plural for Droideka? Is it a non-plural dead stub like the plural of sheep?) But as for B-1's, it seems as though they carry 4368 total.

Comment: @Wasabi (The plural of "droideka" is "droidekas".)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### TL;DR - between 1232 to 1688 battle droids

Thanks to Wookieepedia, and a bit of math, we can calculate how many droids a [C-9979 landing craft](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/C-9979_landing_craft), from the Trade Federation, could carry. For the purposes of this answer, I will be talking about *classic* [B1 battle droids](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/B1-series_battle_droid).

Wookieepedia quotes that a Landing craft can carry **11** Multi-Troop Transports (the same number in [legends](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/C-9979_landing_craft/Legends#cite_note-FF-2) and [canon](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/C-9979_landing_craft#cite_note-Starfighters-3).) Each [Multi-Troop Transport](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Multi-Troop_Transport) can carry **112** B1 battle droids. Now with a little arithmetic (11 * 112), we can find that **a Trade Federation Landing craft can carry 1232 B1 Battle droids if only carrying Multi-troop transports (excluding the 88 crew on the LC and the 2 crew on each MTT).**

If you prefer to have quality over quantity, you could opt for 12 [B2 battle droids](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/B2-series_super_battle_droid) or [20 droidekas](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Multi-Troop_Transport/Legends#cite_note-TCWCG-1) instead, which would give you either **132 B2 battle droids or 220 droidekas per Landing ship (11 * 12 = 132 and 11 * 20 = 220.)**

#### But wait, there's more!

If you take into account that each landing craft also carried 114 [Armored Assault Tanks](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Armored_Assault_Tank), and each of the tanks has a crew of 4 B1 battle droids (as I've never seen a B2s crew a AAT), you get an **additional 456 droids**. And if you included the crew for the landing craft and each MMT you would have to add on 110 (2 crew per MTT, 2 * 11 = 22, and 88 crew from the LC - 88 + 22 = 110.) **Overall, if your landing craft was only carrying B1 battle droids, you would therefore have 1798 droids on board (456 + 1232 + 110 = 1798.)**

Unfortunately, I can't find any hard numbers for how many [troop carriers](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Trade_Federation_troop_carrier) (also known as Platoon Attack craft) a landing craft could carry, but if we assume the same number as MMTs, then we come out with the same number of battle-ready droids.

#### Fun fact

If you take into account that at the Invasion of Naboo there was only one Lucrehulk-class battleship, and one of these battleships can contain 50 landing craft, we can calculate that the Trade federation deployed, at the maximum, 61600 B1 battle droids to the battle (1232 * 50 = 61600).

Comment: In real world terms, you could say that a single regiment (considering a regiment can vary in size from 1,000 - 3,000 soldiers.) (according to wikipedia)

Comment: I will be updating my answer shortly, as I have not had the time recently